# Run TeX-command-master without querying in emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

The key combination *C-c C-c* in Emacs/AucTeX runs the function `TeX-command-master`which decides what command should be run (latex, bibtex, view, or others) and then asks the user for confirmation before running the command.

I would like to bind this to a key (say *F9*) except **without** asking for confirmation. This way I would just press *F9* and the most appropriate command would be run. How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX?

Comment: @Thomas I think it's `11.86-3`. Does that make sense?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this snippet (taken from Emacswiki link below), which does every thing with out bothering me what to do now. I bound to `C-c C-a`

```lisp
;;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TN
(require 'tex-buf)
(defun TeX-command-default (name)
  "Next TeX command to use. Most of the code is stolen from `TeX-command-query'."
  (cond ((if (string-equal name TeX-region)
             (TeX-check-files (concat name "." (TeX-output-extension))
                              (list name)
                              TeX-file-extensions)
           (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
         TeX-command-default)
        ((and (memq major-mode '(doctex-mode latex-mode))
              (TeX-check-files (concat name ".bbl")
                               (mapcar 'car
                                       (LaTeX-bibliography-list))
                               BibTeX-file-extensions))
         ;; We should check for bst files here as well.
         TeX-command-BibTeX)
        ((TeX-process-get-variable name
                                   'TeX-command-next
                                   TeX-command-Show))
        (TeX-command-Show)))

;;;  from wiki
(defcustom TeX-texify-Show t
  "Start view-command at end of TeX-texify?"
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'TeX-command)

(defcustom TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command 5
  "Maximal run number of the same command"
  :type 'integer
  :group 'TeX-command)

(defun TeX-texify-sentinel (&optional proc sentinel)
  "Non-interactive! Call the standard-sentinel of the current LaTeX-process.
If there is still something left do do start the next latex-command."
  (set-buffer (process-buffer proc))
  (funcall TeX-texify-sentinel proc sentinel)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (when (string-match "\\(finished\\|exited\\)" sentinel)
      (set-buffer TeX-command-buffer)
      (unless (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern (TeX-master-file)))
        (TeX-texify)))))

(defun TeX-texify ()
  "Get everything done."
  (interactive)
  (let ((nextCmd (TeX-command-default (TeX-master-file)))
        proc)
    (if (and (null TeX-texify-Show)
             (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
        (when  (called-interactively-p 'any)
          (message "TeX-texify: Nothing to be done."))
      (TeX-command nextCmd 'TeX-master-file)
      (when (or (called-interactively-p 'any)
                (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-count-same-command))
                (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-last-command))
                (null (equal nextCmd TeX-texify-last-command)))
        (mapc 'make-local-variable '(TeX-texify-sentinel TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-last-command))
        (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command 1))
      (if (>= TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command)
          (message "TeX-texify: Did %S already %d times. Don't want to do it anymore." TeX-texify-last-command TeX-texify-count-same-command)
        (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command (1+ TeX-texify-count-same-command))
        (setq TeX-texify-last-command nextCmd)
        (and (null (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
             (setq proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
             (setq TeX-texify-sentinel (process-sentinel proc))
             (set-process-sentinel proc 'TeX-texify-sentinel))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-a") 'TeX-texify)))
```

I have few more AUCTeX/RefTeX settings [here](https://github.com/yyr/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-latex.el), copy if you like.

Comment: I'm getting a `let: Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-command-default` error message as soon as I try to `C-c C-a` (or if I run the function manually). Doing `C-h v TeX-command-default` describes it as a variable.

Comment: @BruceConnor Sorry about that. added total snippet now.

Comment: This is great! I'm wondering, though, if it's possible to get `TeX-command-show` to instead call `TeX-view`, a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-Viewers.html#Starting-Viewers) that opens the PDF viewer on the exact position currently open in the editor.

Comment: This still asks for me to save the file

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could define a keyboard macro containing the following commands:

- `C-x C-s` to save the file
- `M-x TeX-command-master <RET>` to run the preselected (by AucTeX) command.

After defining, `M-x insert-kbd-macro` will insert the macro definition into the current buffer (as Lisp code). Then you can add it to your `.emacs` and bind it to `F9`.